# I'm only assigning one value to my final variable but still I'm getting an error

Tags: java, class, final

I'm getting an error when making my instance Strings cardRank and cardSuit final and I think that I'm only assigning them values once in my code.
I've commented which ones I'm talking about in my code.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Card{

protected static final String[] SUITS = {"spades", "clubs", "hearts", "diamonds"};
protected static final String[] RANKS = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"};

private String cardRank; // I want to make this final
private String cardSuit; // I want to make this final

public Card(){
    this(RANKS[(int) (Math.random() * RANKS.length)] , SUITS[(int) (Math.random() * SUITS.length)]);
}

public Card(String cardRank, String cardSuit){
    setRank(cardRank);
    setSuit(cardSuit);
}

private boolean isValidRank(String cardRank){
    cardRank = cardRank.toUpperCase();
    return Arrays.asList(RANKS).contains(cardRank);
}

private boolean isValidSuit(String cardSuit){
    cardSuit = cardSuit.toLowerCase();
    return Arrays.asList(SUITS).contains(cardSuit);
}

private void setRank(String cardRank){
    if(isValidRank(cardRank)) this.cardRank = cardRank;
    else this.cardRank = "Invalid Suit";
}

private void setSuit(String cardSuit){
    if(isValidSuit(cardSuit)) this.cardSuit = cardSuit;
    else this.cardSuit = "Invalid Suit";
}

public String getRank(){
    return cardRank;
}

public String getSuit(){
    return cardSuit;
}

public void printCard(){      
    System.out.println(getSuit() + " " + getRank());
}
```

}

Comment: You have only one place where you assign a value to them. That is not the same as assigning them only once. Nothing prevents other code from calling the `setRank` and `setSuit` methods multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *only* assign to a `final` field within a constructor body (or as part of the declaration, or an instance initializer). So basically, you should ditch your `setSuit` and `setRank` methods.

```
public Card(String cardRank, String cardSuit) {
    this.cardRank = isValidCardRank(cardRank) ? "Invalid rank";
    this.cardSuit = isValidCardSuit(cardSuit) ? "Invalid suit";
}
```

Or better:

```
public Card(String cardRank, String cardSuit) {
    this.cardRank = validateRank(cardRank);
    this.cardSuit = validateSuit(cardSuit);
}
```

where the `validate*` methods would throw `IllegalArgumentException` if the valid is invalid.

Or better yet, make `Suit` and `Rank` enums, so the *only* values are valid ones, and you just need to check for nullity...

Comment: He could also use static block.

Comment: @mkrakhin: Uh, how? These are instance fields.

Comment: oh, sorry, I thought he was talking about SUITS and RANKS ._. Then he could use instance initialization block.

Comment: @mkrakhin: How, when the value depends on the parameters? You're right that it's valid to assign to a final field in an instance initializer though.

Comment: Just wanted to make first statement more correct (sorry if bothering).

Comment: Thank you it worked. I removed the setters and changed the code in my constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use `enum`, here is an example of your card class. There is no need for validation since the parameters passable are only within the defined `enum`. Since the RANK and SUIT are final you don't need set methods for them.

```
public class Card {

    public enum SUIT {SPADE, CLUB, HEART, DIAMOND};

    public enum RANK {
        ACE("1"), TWO("2"), THREE("3"), FOUR("4"), FIVE("5"), SIX("6"), SEVEN("7"), EIGHT("8"), NINE("9"), TEN("10"), JACK("J"), QUEEN("Q"), KING("K");

        private String value;

        private RANK(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return this.value;
        }
    };


    private final SUIT cardSuit;
    private final RANK cardRank;

    /**
     * Creates a Specific Card
     */
    public Card(SUIT cardSuit, RANK cardRank) {
        this.cardSuit = cardSuit;
        this.cardRank = cardRank;
    }

    /**
     * Generate a Random Card
     */
    public Card(){
        this(RANK.values()[(int) (Math.random() * RANK.values().length)] , SUIT.values()[(int) (Math.random() * SUIT.values().length)]);
    }

    public String getSuit() {
        return cardSuit.toString();
    }

    public String getRank() {
        return cardRank.getValue();
    }

    public void printCard() {
        System.out.println(getSuit() + " " + getRank());
    }

}
```